# Do some quests keep returning infinitely?

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia-mk2, neptunia-rebirth-2

Being obsessive I try to complete all quests in one  area before moving on to the next. However when going to Accept a Quest I just noticed the two "new" quests are actually two quests I just turned in; standard "Kill X number of Y monsters" quests.

If I keep completing these quests will they keep returning as "new" quests or is something else going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of quests in the game are repeatable, but not every single one. There are a couple of the very beginning E-rank quests that can only be performed once (possibly because they're just meant to be introductory). I think this is the full list here, but I'll double check later tonight when I can get on my PS3.

- Defeating Dogoos
- Super Strategy: Spa Conqueror
- Seeking Nep Bull
- Training Regimen
- I'll Never Stop

The first three are just -5% Arfoire, +5% Planeptune in Planeptune. *Training Regimen* is -10% Arfoire, +10% Planeptune in Haneda City, and *I'll Never Stop* is -5% Lastation, +5% Planeptune in Planeptune.

Every other quest is repeatable, though, and there are other quests that accomplish the same share effects as these ones. Just a lot more annoying than handing in all those 99 Herbs you tend to accumulate.

Answer (score 2):

Every quest in the game is repeatable. It's a good way to increase or decrease certain shares while searching for any items you may need.